# Validate a button based on checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the JQuery Validate library and I have a button that when clicked, opens a list of checkboxes that pops up beside the button.  What I am trying to do is if none of the checkboxes are checked when I click submit, place the validation error on the button, so that the .error class is applied to the button so I can set the style to the button rather than the checkbox(s).  Here's basically what I have

```
<button type="button" id="myButton" name="myButton"></button>
<ul id="myListOfCheckboxes">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="checkboxList"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="checkboxList"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="checkboxList"></li>
</ul>
```

and the validation...

```
$("#frmMyForm").validate({
    rules: {
        myButton: { 
            required: {
                function(element) {
                    return $("input[name='checkboxList']").is(":checked");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> place the validation error on the button, so that the .error class is applied to the button so I can set the style to the button rather than the checkbox(s).

You can't directly do this.

You absolutely cannot validate a `button` element using this plugin.  jQuery Validate was only designed to validate elements that contain actual form data:  `select`, `textarea`, certain types of `input` elements, and certain elements with the `contenteditable` attribute.  Nothing else.

<s>A workaround might be that you validate a `type="hidden"` `input` element instead of the `button`.  Place the hidden element near your button so the validation message appears close to where you need it.  Remember to change the `ignore` option within `.validate()` to allow this.</s>

Since the error is triggered when the checkboxes are left blank, you essentially are just validating the `required` rule on the checkboxes!  Since this is the case, you can programmatically apply error classes to the `button` based on the error classes on the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

use this, beacuse input tag having name attribute as `checkboxList` not id

```
$("#frmMyForm").validate({
        rules: {
            myButton: { 
                  required: {
                       function(element) {
                           return $("input[name='checkboxList']").is(":checked");
                       }
              }
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes my mistake.  I have done that correctly, but I didn't type it correctly in my question.  I think the validation check is correct, but it's not applying the .error class to the button correctly

Comment: You cannot validate a `button`!